# Maven war - Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/] building a maven war

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7

I've searched the net for answers, but everything i've found didn't help at all. The issue is this: dynamic web project has been converted to maven project, and deploying it to tomcat7 works just fine, but after building a war file out of same project, and trying to run the same, i'm getting a org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException. I believe that all my dependencies are in place, thus i don't think it's the issue with maven, but rather with maven compiler. Furthermore, building war though eclipse out of the same project, runs just fine on tomcat, but building through maven, doesn't. here's the stack trace:

```
`Jul 12, 2013 11:39:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;D:\install\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;D:\install\apache-ant-1.9.1-bin\apache-ant-1.9.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin;D:\install\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 295 ms
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive D:\install\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\RQM-WEB-MVN-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RQM-WEB-MVN-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1654)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LLog;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2300)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1745)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Log
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 25 more
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive D:\install\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\RQM-WEB-MVN-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RQM-WEB-MVN-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1654)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\install\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\host-manager
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\install\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\manager
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\install\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\ROOT
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 12, 2013 11:39:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8855 ms
`
```

pom.xml is quit large, and it'won't fit, thus unable to post it, but i truly believe that all dependencies are in place... help would be greatly appreciated!

these are my plugins:

```
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/maven*.jar</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days, finally figured out what was the problem. I thought this might help others with similar issues. After building your .war file (either through m2e-wtp, or console mvn package), maven compiler was picking up java classes out of src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes folder instead of target folder (target/projectName/WEB-INF/classes), and thus reporting errors on imports, which caused errors in deploying .war file to tomcat. So, just remove classes folder out of your WEB-INF folder, and maven will take care of it.