# How to run web application without "A child container failed during start" error on Tomcat 7 from Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web-applications

Colleagues, hello. I know that problem like this is discussed in the next threads (or near it):
[Maven war - Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/] building a maven war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612601/maven-war-failed-to-start-component-standardenginecatalina-standardhostloc)
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556201/tomcat-7-0-27-not-starting)
[How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706)
[Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404916/failed-to-start-component-standardenginecatalina-standardhostlocalhost-stan)
[Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JDBC_DBO]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340128/failed-to-start-component-standardenginecatalina-standardhostlocalhost-stan)
but they can not help me.

So I have the same problem when running my web application from eclipse on Tomcat 7.0.61:

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/maya-web-service]]

My pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mycomp.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>maya-proj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.mycomp.proj</groupId>
  <artifactId>maya-web-service</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>maya-web-service Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>maya-web-service</finalName>


    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>

</project>
```

After "**mvn clean package**" next file occurs in target folder:

> • maya-web-service.war maya-web-service\index.jsp
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\classes\com\mycomp\proj\MMayaServiceEndPoindImpl.java
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\classes\com\mycomp\proj\MayaServiceInterface.java
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\commons-digester-2.1.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\FastInfoset-1.2.13.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\gmbal-api-only-3.1.0-b001.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\ha-api-3.1.9.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\javax.xml.soap-api-1.3.7.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\jaxb-api-2.2.12-b140109.1041.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\jaxb-core-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\jaxb-impl-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\jaxws-api-2.2.11.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\jsr181-api-1.0-MR1.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\mimepull-1.9.4.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\policy-2.4.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\resolver-20050927.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\saaj-impl-1.3.25.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\stax-ex-1.7.7.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\streambuffer-1.5.3.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\lib\woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\sun-jaxws.xml
>
> • maya-web-service\WEB-INF\web.xml
>
> • classes\com\mycomp\proj\MayaServiceEndPoindImpl.java
>
> • classes\com\mycomp\proj\MayaServiceInterface.java
>
> • m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
>
> • m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\com.mycomp.proj\maya-web-service\pom.properties
>
> • m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\com.mycomp.proj\maya-web-service\pom.xml
>
> • maven-archiver\pom.properties
>
> • maven-status\maven-compiler-plugin\compile\default-compile\inputFiles.lst
>
> • maven-status\maven-compiler-plugin\testCompile\default-testCompile\inputFiles.lst

After right clicking on the project and selecting "**Run on server**" i receive next log in console:

```
may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
> [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
> property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:maya-web-service'
> did not find a matching property.  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
> version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.61  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
> built:          Mar 27 2015 12:03:56 UTC  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
> number:         7.0.61.0  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS Name:  
> Windows 7  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS
> Version:            6.1  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
> Architecture:          amd64  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Java Home:
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
> Version:           1.8.0_40-b26  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
> Vendor:            Oracle Corporation  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
> CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software
> Foundation\Tomcat 7.0  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
> CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software
> Foundation\Tomcat 7.0  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
> line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
> Foundation\Tomcat 7.0  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
> line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
> Foundation\Tomcat 7.0  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
> line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
> Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
> line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
> Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
> line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1251  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO: The
> APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal
> performance in production environments was not found on the
> java.library.path: C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program
> Files/Java/jre1.8.0_40/bin/server;C:/Program
> Files/Java/jre1.8.0_40/bin;C:/Program
> Files/Java/jre1.8.0_40/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Oracle_client\instantclient_11_2;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
> Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
> Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
> SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
> Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;C:\graphviz-2.38\release\bin;D:\Distr\eclipse-java-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
> may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
> Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]  may 05, 2015 2:55:10
> PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
> ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
> processed in 1057 ms  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
> service Catalina  may 05, 2015 2:55:10 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
> Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.61  may 05, 2015 2:55:11 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child
> container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/maya-web-service]]
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/maya-web-service]]
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>   ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/sun/istack/localization/Localizable   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)   at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)   at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)    at
> java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)     at
> java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)    at
> org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:89)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5416)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.sun.istack.localization.Localizable   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>   ... 34 more may 05, 2015 2:55:11 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child
> container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455) Caused
> by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
> during start  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ... 6 more may 05, 2015 2:55:11 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start SEVERE: The required Server
> component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardServer[8005]]    at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455) Caused
> by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
> to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
> container failed during start     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ... 11 more may 05, 2015 2:55:11 PM
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler
> ["http-bio-8080"]  may 05, 2015 2:55:11 PM
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler
> ["ajp-bio-8009"]  may 05, 2015 2:55:11 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFO: Stopping
> service Catalina  may 05, 2015 2:55:11 PM
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
> ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]  may 05, 2015 2:55:11 PM
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
> ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

How to run web application without "A child container failed during start" mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root cause of the problem is NoClassDefFound exception which is due to a missing Class `com.sun.istack.localization.Localizable`. So you need to include the `jaxb-core` or `jaxb-impl` jar file in your project's pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

or add this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this solves your issue.